# How to change table data in react with buttons in modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Hi i have  problem with my react components. I don't know how to update element in table from shared modal for all elements. In my real case i have students timetable and i have to edit columns with subjects. After I click on subject in table, modal should open and after i choosed which subject i want to input it should change. I prepeared basic model of situation on codeblox. Please how should i access to specific column throught this modal and update that column with value of button. Thx for help

This is my example on codeblox:

Here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-butterfly-g8dr1
**IMPORTANT: You have to remove BUTTON in Todo component and paste it back.. idk why but otherside it not works.**
!!! i was unable to run bootstrap but it is not important

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

export default class Col extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.data}</div>;
  }
}

class Todo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [
        { Firstname: "Jill", Lastname: "Bill", Age: 18 },
        { Firstname: "Jill2", Lastname: "Bill2", Age: 180 },
        { Firstname: "Jill3", Lastname: "Bill3", Age: 1 }
      ],
      modal: false
    };
  }

  renderColumn() {
    return this.state.items.map(i => (
      <tr>
        <td>
          <Col data={i.Firstname} />
        </td>
        <td>
          <Col data={i.Lastname} />
        </td>
        <td>
          <Col data={i.Age} />
        </td>
      </tr>
    ));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead />
          <tbody>{this.renderColumn()}</tbody>
        </table>
        <Button
          variant="primary"
          onClick={() => this.setState({ modal: true })}
        >
          Launch vertically centered modal
        </Button>
        <p>------------------------------------------------------</p>
        <MyModal
          show={this.state.modal}
          onHide={() => this.setState({ modal: true })}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export class MyModal extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal.Dialog>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal title</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>

        <Modal.Body>
          <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
        </Modal.Body>

        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary">Mark</Button>
          <Button variant="primary">Joseph</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal.Dialog>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Real situation looks like this:
[Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7Bc3.png)

Those blue buttons are subjects. After i click one of the button in timetable -> modal will open and after i choose one -> value in timetable should change

Comment: where are subjects in table?

Comment: this is just example. My code is bigger i wrote it above. In this case  this.state.items are my subjects for example. It is same principe i used in my project

Comment: How do you want to filter them and where to filter them? from which button you will select subjects?

Comment: in example ```<Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary">Mark</Button>
          <Button variant="primary">Joseph</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal.Dialog> ``` Mark and Joseph should be value for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scenario might work for you:

1. add `selectedStudent: null,` to the `Todo` component state
2. remove button which have text "Launch vertically centered modal"
3. add new button to each row of students. Name it something like "Select"
4. add new method to Todo component e.g. `selectStudent` which will have one argument - student object. Also this method might use `setState` with callback. Callback will open the modal (by changing state `modal: true`). This method is what will be fired when you click on "Select" button
5. pass new prop to the modal: `selectedStudent` which value will be `this.state.selectedStudent`
6. when modal get closed - set `selectedStudent` to `null` again

If something seems confusing here or you need further explanation please ask

N.B. you might also remove `modal` key from state and conditionally render modal only when `selectedStudent` is an object. When `selectedStudent` is `null` - modal should be closed.

Comment: You answered me how to get student object to modal. And how should i change value ? Becouse i can't change directly student from props. Data are saved in table so how can i acces to this student which i selected?

Comment: Can you create another post for that because your last q doesn't fit well with your post title ("How to change table data in react with buttons in modal")? Do not forget to explain from where your props comes from (redux, another componet state or from remote api). Just add link to that new post here so I can join discussion. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60979021/how-to-update-data-for-table-column Thx for helping

Comment: No problem . Glad to hap :)