# How to update data for table column in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Hi i have problem with my table in bootstrap. I am getting data from server about timetable. This data i am saving in state. Next i am creating table. (Two ways of creating mobile and pc, just changing position of days and hours). Every column contains component SubjectColumn (there will be more data in one column like class and subject name). So when I click on this subject column i need to open modal with clicked subject data and after choosing of list of subjects in modal, I have to change subject for new one. I get subject data in my modal but i don't know how to change them for new one. Any idea please?

```
export class Schedule extends Component {
    static contextType = LoggedInuserContext;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            editMode: false,
            openModal: false,
            schedule: null,
            modalShow: false,
            mySubjects: null,
            selectedSubject:null
        };

        this.resize = () => this.forceUpdate();
    }

    changeModalState() {
        this.setState({modalShow: !this.state.modalShow})
    }


    selectSubject(subject){
        this.setState({selectedSubject:subject},this.changeModalState);
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.resize)
        this.getTimeTable().then(r =>
            this.setState({isScheduleLoaded: true})
        );
        this.getMySubjects();
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resize)
    }

    async getTimeTable() {
        if (this.context == null) return;
        const response = await fetch('UserController/GetTimeTable/' + this.context.user.id + '/' + this.context.company + '/' + this.context.role.id);
        this.setState({schedule: await response.json()});
    }

    async getMySubjects() {
        if (this.context == null) return;
        const response = await fetch('SubjectTreeController/GetUserSubjectsList/' + this.context.user.id + '/' + this.context.company + '/' + this.context.role.id);
        this.setState({mySubjects: await response.json()});
    }

    createContent() {
        if (!this.state.isScheduleLoaded === true) return;

        let header_data = [];
        let body_data = [];

        //For mobile else pc
        if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
            //Header of table
            this.state.schedule.days.forEach(day => {
                header_data.push(day.name.substring(0, 2))
            });

            //Body of table
            for (let i = 0; i < this.state.schedule.days[0].slots.length; i++) {
                let row = {
                    firstColumn: i,
                    other: []
                };
                this.state.schedule.days.forEach((day, key) => {
                    row.other.push(day.slots[i]);
                });

                body_data.push(row);
            }
        } else {
            //Header of table
            this.state.schedule.days[0].slots.forEach(slot => {
                header_data.push(slot.order)
            });

            //Body of table
            this.state.schedule.days.forEach(day => {
                let row = {
                    firstColumn: [],
                    other: []
                };
                row.firstColumn.push(day.name);
                day.slots.map(slot => row.other.push(slot));
                body_data.push(row);
            });
        }

        let head = this.createTableHead(header_data);
        let body = this.createRows(body_data);

        return (
            <>
                <thead>
                {head}
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                {body}
                </tbody>
            </>
        );
    }

    createTableHead(data) {
        return (
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                {data.map((d, k) => {
                    return (<th key={k} className={"text-center"}> {d} </th>)
                })}
            </tr>
        );
    }

    createRows(data) {
        const items = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            const row = [];

            for (let j = 0; j < data[i].other.length; j++) {
                if (data[i].other[j].subject !== null) {
                    row.push(<td key={j} className={"text-center "}><SubjectColumn editMode={this.state.editMode}
                                                                                   subject={data[i].other[j].subject}
                                                                                    selectSubject={this.selectSubject.bind(this)}>
                    </SubjectColumn>
                    </td>);
                } else {
                    row.push(<td key={j} className={"text-center "}><SubjectColumn editMode={this.state.editMode}
                                                                                   subject={null}
                                                                                   selectSubject={this.selectSubject.bind(this)}
                                                                                   >
                                                                                   </SubjectColumn>
                    </td>);
                }
            }

            items.push(
                <tr key={i}>
                    <td>{data[i].firstColumn}</td>
                    {row}
                </tr>
            );
        }
        return items;

    }

    loading() {
        if (this.state.schedule === null)
            return (
                <div className={"d-flex flex-column justify-content-center text-center"}>
                    <div>
                        <Spinner animation="grow" variant="success"/>
                        <Spinner animation="grow" variant="danger"/>
                        <Spinner animation="grow" variant="warning"/>
                    </div>
                    <span>Načítam rozvrh</span>
                </div>
            );
    }

    showActionButtons() {
        const items = [];

        if (this.state.editMode) {
            items.push(<Button key={"save"} className={"px-4 mx-1"} variant={"success"}
                               onClick={this.startEditing.bind(this)}>Uložiť</Button>)
        }
        items.push(
            <Dropdown key={"settings"} alignRight>
                <Dropdown.Toggle variant="dark" id="dropdown-basic">
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCog} size={"lg"}/>
                </Dropdown.Toggle>

                <Dropdown.Menu>
                    <Dropdown.Item onClick={this.startEditing.bind(this)}>Edituj rozvrh</Dropdown.Item>
                </Dropdown.Menu>
            </Dropdown>
        );
        return items;
    }

    startEditing() {
        this.setState({editMode: !this.state.editMode});
    }


    openScheduleSetting() {
        console.log("open");
//        this.setState({openModal: true});
    }

    closeScheduleSetting() {
        console.log("close");

        //      this.setState({openModal: false});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={"w-100"} id="schedule">
                <div className={"d-flex justify-content-center my-2"}>
                    <h3 className={"my-1 text-left flex-grow-1  pl-2"}>Rozvrh hodín</h3>
                    {this.showActionButtons()}
                </div>
                <Table striped bordered hover>
                    {this.createContent()}
                </Table>
                {this.loading()}
                <ScheduleSelectModal subject={this.state.selectedSubject} subjectslist={this.state.mySubjects} show={this.state.modalShow} onHide={this.changeModalState.bind(this)}>
                </ScheduleSelectModal>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

SubjectColumn

```
export class SubjectColumn extends Component {

    showModalInParrent(){
        console.log(this.props);
        this.props.selectSubject(this.props.subject);
    }

    createCell() {
        let items = null;
        if (this.props.editMode) {
            if(this.props.subject === null){
                return (  <Button className={"w-100 h-100"} onClick={this.showModalInParrent.bind(this)}>  </Button>)
            }

            items = (
                <Fragment>
                    <Button className={"w-100 h-100"} onClick={this.showModalInParrent.bind(this)}> {this.props.subject.acronym } </Button>
                </Fragment>
            );
            return items;
        } else {
            if(this.props.subject === null){
            return;
            }

            return (this.props.subject.acronym  );
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="w-100 h-100">
                {this.createCell()}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Modal:

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from "react";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import ButtonGroup from "react-bootstrap/ButtonGroup";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

export class ScheduleSelectModal extends Component {

   componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
       console.log("modal props:");
       console.log(this.props.subject);
   }

    createList() {
        let items = [];
        if (this.props.subjectslist !== null)
            this.props.subjectslist.map(subject =>
                items.push(<Button key={subject.id} block className={"my-1"}>{subject.name} </Button>)
            );

        return items;
    }

    renderHeader(){
       if(this.props.subject === null){
           return(
               <p>
                   Vyberťe subjekt ktorý chcete nahradiť
               </p>
           )
       }
       else{
          return(   <p>
              {this.props.subject.name }
          </p>);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Modal
                {...this.props}
                size="lg"
                aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
                centered
            >
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                    <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                        {this.renderHeader()}
                    </Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <ButtonGroup vertical className={"w-100"}>
                        {this.createList()}
                    </ButtonGroup>
                </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>
        );
    }
}
```

This loos like my shedule object

```
Object
id: 1
dateUpdated: "2020-03-24T17:36:48.66"
days: Array(5)
0: {slots: Array(8), id: 1, order: 1, name: "Pondelok", acronym: "PO", …}
1:
slots: Array(8)
0: {order: 0, subject: null, studentGroup: null}
1: {order: 1, subject: null, studentGroup: null}
2: {order: 2, subject: {…}, studentGroup: null}
3:
order: 3
subject:
note: ""
id: 5
name: "Biológia"
acronym: "B"
__proto__: Object
studentGroup: null
__proto__: Object
4: {order: 4, subject: {…}, studentGroup: null}
5: {order: 5, subject: null, studentGroup: null}
6: {order: 6, subject: null, studentGroup: null}
7: {order: 7, subject: null, studentGroup: null}
length: 8
__proto__: Array(0)
id: 2
order: 2
name: "Utorok"
acronym: "UT"
isWeekend: 0
__proto__: Object
2: {slots: Array(8), id: 3, order: 3, name: "Streda", acronym: "ST", …}
3: {slots: Array(8), id: 4, order: 4, name: "Štvrtok", acronym: "ŠT", …}
4: {slots: Array(8), id: 5, order: 5, name: "Piatok", acronym: "PIA", …}
length: 5
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: For more info. I don'' know how to acces to CHOSEN data in schedule table state and change them from my modal

Comment: Data you wan't to edit and send to api (make PUT request) is data you have in your modal?

Comment: There are 2 types in modal: SubjectList -> there are new data for changing... User can choose from them to pick whatever subject to put in column. Second data are selected subject -> this data should be null OR subject which was before in table. I need to change selectedSubject for one of subject in subjectList after i click to someone

Comment: could you provide a working example through `codesandbox` or semthing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60907787/how-to-change-table-data-in-react-with-buttons-in-modal/60908447#60908447 I made here some easy example on my situation. If it will be neccessary i will try to remake this example again. But i have always truble  use libs in codeexample

Answer (score 0):

If I've undeerstood your q, this might work for you:

1. In the modal where you show `selectedSubject`, replace each value (text) you want to edit with input element.
2. changing value in input should update `state.selectedSubject` in `Schedule` component or you might have state in modal to capture edited `selectedSubject`, but why duplicating data if you don't have to. I would go with updating parent component state.
3. `Schedule` component should have method which will make put (or patch) request with edited data.
4. Pass this method to the modal.
5. Add "Save" button to the modal. When you finish editing, clicking on "Save" button should fire passed method.
6. Optional: you can have success message in your modal (success or error)

Comment: In 1 phase you mean what exactly please? Button value?

Comment: in modal there are buttons. Each button represent object (Subject) in my database. There is no input

Comment: My data structure is Schedule->SelectedSubject (one column from schedule). So my question is if i change data in selectedSubject with setState() ithen I think data in schedule won't change? Or no?

Comment: Can you create demo on codesandox and I'll take a look at tomorrow?

Comment: I thin i get something. I try it and if it won't work i'll let you know about codesandbox